# What are the priors in Bayesian Neural Network?

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian-network

So I have knowledge of Bayesian statistics/econometrics, but I only recently found out about Bayesian Neural Networks. I was wondering what the priors are in a Bayesian Neural Network?

And is it possible to give an importance weight to different input features? Or have the ability to shrink features with a prior?

Basically, I am trying to see if Neural Networks can be used in a setting where the number of observations is not very large by performing feature selection. However, instead of feature selection I thought about including all features and give prior weights to the features based on the outcomes of the feature selection step. Is this possible?

Comment: One of the earliest treatments of "Bayesian Neural Networks" is Radford Neal's *Bayesian Learning for Neural Networks* (1996) and it includes a section on "automatic relevance determination" models (McKay) that can be used for feature selection.